# Background service killed on App close in LeEco device only

Tags: android, background-service

Background service killed on App close in LeEco devices with following error

```
ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@8eeaafc startId=3 args=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000
```

Comment: have you got the solution of this problem?
Because i am facing the same issue.

Comment: set android:excludeFromRecents="true" for the activity in which you are starting the service and make sure service is START_STICKY.

Comment: Still not working :/

Comment: That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the app
2. Go to recent apps by pressing leftmost button
3. Swipe down the app which you wanna work in background.
4. You will see a **lock** at the top of that app
   Your services will be running in background forever